# How do I fix the merger failure of AndroidManifest.xml file to ensure Flutter build appbundle works?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, android-app-bundle

Right now I am trying to build my appbundle in flutter using the following command:

`flutter build appbundle --release`

and receive the following error:

```
 Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

I have run with stack trace, info and debug and nothing useful comes out of it.

and after trying many solutions, mostly removing packages or manually adding android:export="true", any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to run flutter build appbundle and expected an app bundle file to be generated. This works for sdk version 30 and target version 30, but at 31 I get the error previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
android:exported="true"
```

in `./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

in **activity** section near

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

it will look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label=""
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem was due to the fact I did not have this receiver

```
   <receiver
    android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

There was no receiver set for this specific package in the AndroidManifest.xml file